# SQL Query to find Woocommerce products that have not sold

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to set up a query that will find products that havn't sold within a time frame and a count.  For example I want to find all products within the last year that have sold less than 50 times.  I am not sure what is wrong with my query but here it is:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` t1 
  INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` t2 
    ON t1.ID = t2.product_id 
  WHERE t2.access_granted >= "2016-04-30 00:00:00" 
  HAVING COUNT(t2.product_id) <= 50;
```

The result is always empty even though I know that there are products that have sold less than 50 times within the last year.

Comment: Please share sample data and expected output.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by sample data.  Its all woocommerce products so I would expect to get a result of everything in the wp_posts table joining the woocommerce downloads table where there are 50 or less product IDs in the downloads table.

Comment: Table structure and some dummy values in it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is empty because you are using `Having` clause without `group by` which will count all the rows in the table.
I am assuming your table contains more than 50 rows hence the result will always be empty as `count(t2.product_id)` will always be > 50.

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.product_id
FROM `wp_posts` t1 INNER JOIN `wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` t2 ON t1.ID = t2.product_id 
WHERE t2.access_granted >= "2016-04-30 00:00:00" 
group by t2.product_id
HAVING COUNT(t2.product_id) <= 50;
```

Comment: Ah yes i see now.  That was it.  Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider accepting the answer if your issue is solved.